# OOP - Common property on list of objects

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm building a list of objects.

It looks like this :

```
var item = {} // new object
item['d'] = {
    element: 'string',
    val_1: false,
    val_2: false,
    val_3: false
}
```

Each of these objects can belong to a sort of family or class. I'm not understanding fully to concept of class in OOP.

I would have two families : left and right.

What I'd like to do, instead of doing something like this :

```
item['d_right'] = {
    element: 'Whatever',
    val_1: false,
    val_2: false,
    val_3: false
}

item['d_left'] = {
    element: 'Something',
    val_1: false,
    val_2: false,
    val_3: false
}
```

Would be to have something like this :

```
class right {

    item['d'] = {
        element: 'Whatever',
        val_1: false,
        val_2: false,
        val_3: false
    }

    // Other elements from the class right

}

class left {

    item['d'] = {
        element: 'Something',
        val_1: false,
        val_2: false,
        val_3: false
    }

    // Other elements from the class left

}
```

And then, being able to call it easily like :

```
console.log(item[left][d].element) // would echo "Something"
```

Is it a way to do something like this ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: My suggestion is if you are trying to learn OOP do not use javascript. Use a language that is better suited towards it's concepts.

Comment: Yes! Especially if you wanna learn about class based OOP, because JS class keyword is not actually class based OOP but syntactic sugar around prototyped based OOP.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not trying to learn OOP, I have to use javascript to do this thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it works for Javascript, use it wisely

```
class middle {      
  constructor(element) {
    this.var1 = 1;
    this.var2 = 2;
    this.element = element;
  }
}

class left extends middle {
  constructor() {
    // calls the constructor of middle
    super("left_element")
  }
}

var myLeft = new left()
myLeft.var1 // -> 1
```

However, there are a lot of discussions, if it is good or not, because as others already said it is more a syntactic sugar on top of the prototyping features from js..

Personally I am not using it, in most cases an object or function is enough to work with in javascript.

However in some cases you have to work with classes, so to know how it works is not a bad idea.